# Can't ssh to server when the ~/.ssh/environment is error

Tags: ssh

I changed the `~/.ssh/environment` on my server, but there seems something wrong, so I can't login with ssh. So, how to solve this? Can I disable loading the `environment` file?

When I ssh to the server, it shows:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Mon Aug  4 18:45:40 CST 2014

  System load:  0.01               Processes:           97
  Usage of /:   15.7% of 19.56GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 25%                IP address for eth0: 10.4.11.179
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

25 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

*** System restart required ***
Last login: Mon Aug  4 18:28:41 2014 from xxx.xx.xx.xxx
[]
Connection to optica.llsapp.com closed.
```

The cursor will stop at the `[]` of the second line from the bottom for a while, then shows the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I just enter `ctrl-c` when the cursor stops at there, then I login successfully.